# Error: Data conversion failed while loading Multiple .csv files into single SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

**Issue Definition:**

We ain't able to load the data from multiple excel sheets in a folder into a single SQL database table on the SQL server. I have used a forloop container for retrieving multiple files and a mutiple flat file connection manager. The error is thrown at the Multi flat files source component. Not able to understand the conversion it is trying to make on the data because of which it is failing.

**Error code mentioned below:**

```
[Flat File Source [61]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column ""OriginalHireDate"" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

[Flat File Source [61]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["OriginalHireDate"]" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["OriginalHireDate"]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[Flat File Source [61]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "F:\CCHC\ADP\Incremental_ADP\ADP_PayData_Final1032020.csv" on data row 4209.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

**What Troubleshooting has been done so far :**

I changed the page code on a multi flat files connection manager and tried to run the ETL but failed. Actually if I keep the page code to 65001 then it is loading the data but at the row no 4209 it is merging the columns due to which we are getting the merged column data. I also created a new package to run ETL for a single file data into the SQL table using a flat-file source but, even that failed. Not able to understand what conversion it is trying to make on the data because of which it is failing. Created new destination component are remapped all the columns with flat file source but the execution still failed. We tried changing the size for taking the long input.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is saying that data will be lost, likely you're trying to insert a numerical value that is too large into another, or a string that is too long for the size of the column. For example an `integer` value `123456789` into a `numeric(5,1)`, or the `varchar` value `'abcdefg'` into an `nvarchar(2)`.

Comment: @Larnu We tried changing the size but that didnt work.

Comment: Actually if I keep the page code to 65001 then it is loading the data but at the row no 4209 it is merging the columns due to which we are getting bad data.

Comment: this is a date field? Are you trying to put a string in there? Also, i've run into this error where there is a non-quote wrapped comma before this column causing the columns to shift.

Comment: Yes , it is a date field.

Comment: the columns are comma separated.

Comment: Can you please tell me the complete solution for this issue in the answer section?

Comment: We resolved this by changing the delimiter of the flat file connection manager before but again after some days stuck with the same error. What have you tried to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks @KeithL for teh hints.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Solution No 1: Check data types:**

We changed the data types of the destination component as per the source data types using

Show Advance Editor ->Input Output Properties ->OLE DB Destination Input

Now expand the OLE DB Destination Input by clicking the (+) and check the data types in properties window on the right side and do this for every column in External Columns and Internal Columns.
In my case it was Unicode string [DT_WSTR] for date columns.

---

**Solution No2: Multiple flat files connection manager editor**

For more details refer microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/multiple-flat-files-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15

I have used Text qualifier ":
Specify the text qualifier to use. For example, you can specify to enclose text with quotation marks.

Link to refer if you are facing issues with Text Qualifier :

Get rid of Double Quotes in CSV file using Text Qualifier in SSIS
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/text-qualifier-in-ssis/

Check header row delimiter:

I have used Comma {,}

Code page:

I have used 65001 UTF-8

Description- Rows are delimited by a comma.

---

**Solution No3: Code page**

There are two settings need to be made for code page:

1. Multiple flat files connection manager editor

   I have used 65001 UTF-8

   Description- Rows are delimited by a comma.
2. OLE DB Destination component properties inside DFT

   Right click on the OLE DB Destination ->Properties

   Set True for AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage setting.

   Now set DefaultCodePage as 65001 same one that you used in multiple flat file source
   connection manager editor.

   Also check if UsesDespositions is set true.

Hope this solution helps all to solve their issues related to this error. Good Luck!